# mongo aggregation to elemMatch on nested arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document like;

```
{
    "name": "abc"
    "array1": [
        {
            "_id": "87a015b3-b81c-4c75-8dd6-4fa0bd6d9660",
            "array2": [
                [
                   {
                        "_id": "123",    
                        "values": [{
                                "value": "ABC"
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    .....
                    .....
                ],

                [
                    {
                        "_id": "789",
                        "values": [{
                                "value": "XYZ"
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    .....
                    .....
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can we do $elemMatch to filter based on _id and values? 
For example, match if there is an entry with  "_id" = "123" and "value" = "ABC" inside array1.array2 .

Comment: Share what you have tried (your query), not only the question.

Comment: do you sure in `array2` structure?
there is a array in array

Comment: Yes, that's the case. array1 will always have 1 element. So we can have an unwind stage for that. But array2 will have array inside array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
db.collection.find(
{"array1.array2": {$elemMatch: {$elemMatch: {_id: "123", "values.value": "ABC"}}}}
)
```

I personally recommend you guys reconsider you're document structure as currently i feel like it does not make much sense to me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is a special case to keep the data structure like this for now. We will be changing it soon. How can I write a Criteria query for this? As it has multiple $elemMatch, is it possible with Criteria object?